# .htaccess - infinite loop redirect, works fine locally

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I was hoping you could help me with something. I have the following htaccess on the root of my website. The idea is that whenever you enter [mywebsite]/[country_code] you get redirected to [mywebsite]/teaser.php?country=[country_code]
When I test it locally on my apache, it works perfectly; but when I upload it to my webserver, it enters an infinite loop of [mywebsite]/[country_code]/[country_code]/[country_code]/etc...
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^cl\/*$ teaser.php?country=cl
RewriteRule ^ar\/*$ teaser.php?country=ar 
RewriteRule ^br\/*$ teaser.php?country=br 
RewriteRule ^bo\/*$ teaser.php?country=bo 
RewriteRule ^co\/*$ teaser.php?country=co 
RewriteRule ^cl\/*$ teaser.php?country=cl 
RewriteRule ^la-ec\/*$ teaser.php?country=la-ec
RewriteRule ^py\/*$ teaser.php?country=py 
RewriteRule ^pe\/*$ teaser.php?country=pe 
RewriteRule ^ve\/*$ teaser.php?country=ve 
RewriteRule ^cr\/*$ teaser.php?country=cr 
RewriteRule ^cu\/*$ teaser.php?country=cu 
RewriteRule ^mx\/*$ teaser.php?country=mx 
RewriteRule ^ni\/*$ teaser.php?country=ni 
RewriteRule ^pa\/*$ teaser.php?country=pa 
RewriteRule ^sv\/*$ teaser.php?country=sv 
RewriteRule ^gt\/*$ teaser.php?country=gt 
RewriteRule ^ht\/*$ teaser.php?country=ht 
RewriteRule ^hn\/*$ teaser.php?country=hn 
RewriteRule ^do\/*$ teaser.php?country=do 
RewriteRule ^uy\/*$ teaser.php?country=uy
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't these many rules. Just use a simple regex to combine all rules into a single rule and retest:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?)/?$ teaser.php?country=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to make sure that this work for that specific set of country codes, and not for any combination of two letters. Thanks though!

Comment: Why would any link be like `domain.com/xy`? Links will be created by you for some known country codes only like `domain.com/pa` OR `domain.com/co`

Comment: I'm not creating any link, that is the idea, I have just one file, teaser.php, that acts different depending on the country you pass as a parameter. If you put any of the valid country codes, it goes to the teaser with that country, but if you input a random combination of two letters, it should throw you a 404, and not do the redirection to teaser.php.

Comment: With your code, if I put domain.com/xy it will take me to teaser.php?country=xy... I don't want that, I want that case to throw a 404 error, because you wrote an invalid country code

Comment: Quite simply done by creating an array of supported country code in `teaser.php`. At the start check if GET parameter is in the array, if not throw a 404 status code.

Comment: Ok, I can try that, yeah... I would have wanted to just not allow the combination to exist, but if that's not possible I guess I'll go with that option.
Thanks!